# CSS media queries overruling each other

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a couple media queries in my stylesheet, each modifying some styles, but not others. I'm using the `max-width` query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #header .span6 { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px; }
    #error .span6 { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px; }
    #timer-block { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px;}
    #timer { font-size: 5em; }
    #start-pause { margin-left: 200px; }
    .control { width: 297px; margin-top: 0; }
    #footer { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #header .span6 { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px; }
    #error .span6 { width: 80; margin-left: 75px; }
    #timer-block { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px;}
    #timer { font-size: 5em; }
    #start-pause { margin-left: 75px; }
    .control { width: 300px; margin-top: -5px; }
    #footer { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #header .span6 { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px; }
    h1 { font-size: 3.5em; margin-bottom: 0px;}
    #error .span6 { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px; }
    #timer-block { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px; }
    #timer { font-size: 5em; }
    .little { font-size: 0.5em; }
    #start-pause { margin-left: 75px; }
    .control { width: 312px; margin-top: -5px; }
    #footer { width: 80%; margin-left: 75px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #header .span6 { width: 90%; margin-left: 25px; }
    #error .span6 { width: 90%; margin-left: 30px; }
    #timer-block { width: 90%; margin-left: 30px;}
    #start-pause { margin-left: 30px; }
    .control { width: 264px; margin-top: -5px; }
    #footer { width: 90%; margin-left: 25px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    #header { margin-top: -10px; }
    #header .span6 { width: 90%; margin-left: 25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 3em; margin-left: -15px; padding-left: 10px; }
    #interval { width: 150px; height: 40px; font-size: 2em; margin-bottom: 20px; width: 150px; }
    #error .span6 { width: 90%; margin-left: 25px; }
    #timer-block { width: 90%; margin-left: 24px; height: 100px; padding: 10px; }
    #start-pause { margin-left: 25px; }
    .control { margin-top: -5px; width: 210px; }
    #footer { width: 100%; margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 0; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
    #timer-block { width: 90%; margin-left: 15px; padding: 10px; font-size: 0.8em; }
    #header { margin-top: 0px; }
    #header .span6 { margin-left: 37px; }
    #interval { margin-top: -45px; margin-left: 20px; }
    #error .span6 { width: 90%; margin-left: 15px; }
    .control { width: 141px; margin-top: -10px; }
    #start-pause { margin-left: 15px; }
    #footer { width: 95%; margin-left: 10px; }
}
```

Is there a way I can change what I'm doing to make there be no collisions? This is the first time I use media queries so I may be missing something entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

You can use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 321px)
```

This way it will look only at screen sizes between 320 and 481;
instead of 0 and 481

Answer (score 2):

Set a min width 1 pixel higher than the max width of the next query

Example

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #header .span6 { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px; }
    #error .span6 { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px; }
    #timer-block { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px;}
    #timer { font-size: 5em; }
    #start-pause { margin-left: 200px; }
    .control { width: 297px; margin-top: 0; }
    #footer { width: 60%; margin-left: 200px; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `min-width` in this case to prevent collision, for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```